# how to make checkbox ticked necessary to submit in Bootstrap

Tags: html, forms, bootstrap-5

I am building Bootstrap’s form, where I want users only submit once the checkbok is ticked (checked).[image]

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Just add `required` to your checkbox. If that's not enough, you can write some JavaScript, but you should always be checking the value on the server regardless of what you deliver on the client side

Answer (score 0):

// Check
`document.getElementById("exampleCheck1").checked = true;`

// Uncheck
`document.getElementById("exampleCheck1").checked = false;`

Answer (score 0):

You can add `disabled` property to button and control it by checkbox

[image]

here's full code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap 5</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container mt-2">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
      <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1" onchange="document.getElementById('exampleButton1').disabled = !this.checked;">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="exampleButton1" disabled>Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```